# Migrating users from Devise to Keycloak

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, keycloak

Is it possible to migrate users from Rails to Keycloak along with the encrypted passwords?
I am using Devise for user management in Rails. I need to keep the migration seamless such that users can login to Keycloak using their old password.

Comment: https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/legacy-system-to-keycloak-migration-strategy/213 - you'd still need Devise (at least the authentication bits)

Comment: Any luck migrating users to Keycloak? I am considering doing the same.

Comment: @user5056973 Didn't succeed with that. I think we decided on resending the password reset link to the users.